# What word can be used to describe 'not belonging to a country'?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, compounds

I'm looking for a word which can be used to describe a location upon the earth which does not belong to a country. For example 'North America' though the word 'continent' can be used here. Another example would be the 'Mid-Atlantic Ridge'.

Words like 'location' or 'toponym' are not specific enough and could equally be used to describe somewhere within a country.

Within a sentence I would use it something like:

"The Mid-Atlantic ridge doesn't belong to a country, so it is (countryless)"

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are posing a single word request. For those it is required to provide example sentences how you would use it. Also a bit more context about how small or big or specific those places are would help.

Comment: @Helmar This word is to be used as a variable name within a computer programming language, therefore there is no sentence within which it can be used.

Comment: In that case the question is actually off-topic **Naming, including naming programming variables/classes is off-topic**. However the search for such a word seems valid enough in my opinion. So just make up a sentence you would put in your documentation to describe it. ;)

Comment: @Helmar Oh, I didn't realize it was off-topic. I'll update the question.

Comment: For people you use [stateless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stateless).

Comment: @Matsmath: my thought also; and even better(?) in computer programming both 'stateless' and 'stateful' and the root 'state' are widely used with a quite different meaning, thus increasing the likelihood programmers will misunderstand this, causing mistakes and bugs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the following term for territories that don't belong to anybody

> [Terra nullius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_nullius)
>
> Terra nullius (/ˈtɛrə.nʌˈlaɪəs/, plural terrae nullius) is a Latin
>   expression deriving from Roman law meaning "nobody's land",[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_nullius) which
>   is used in international law to describe territory which has never
>   been subject to the sovereignty of any state, or over which any prior sovereign has expressly or implicitly relinquished sovereignty.

It applies to your example of the mid-ridge Atlantic or other geographical features.

**"The Mid-Atlantic ridge doesn't belong to a country, so it is terra nullius"**

> Under the United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea of 1982, the
>   international waters and **international seabed** are treated under the
>   common heritage of mankind principle by the signatories of the
>   convention.

if it's a piece of land above sea you can also simply say

> Unclaimed territory

You'd get thousand of hits on Google for it and it's the most commonly used term.

But for things owned by several countries, like North-America, then

> **[international](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/international)**

is the right word to use, in its strictest sense.

> of, concerning, or involving two or more nations or nationalities

For example "The Himalayas are  an international mountain range"

See also [The Helsinki Rules on the Uses of the Waters of **International Rivers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Helsinki_Rules_on_the_Uses_of_the_Waters_of_International_Rivers)  set up mainly to deal with the Nile situation.

Comment: Perfect. I especially like the 'null' prefix to the word as it has a special meaning in computer languages.

Answer (score 6):

The prefix [*extra-*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/extra?s=t) can be used to mean 'outside', with examples given of 'extrajudical' (meaning outside the judiciary) and the obvious 'extraterrestial'.

'Extranational' would be a reasonable construct to mean 'outside of any nation'.